# Proving equivalencies of these sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$(A \cap B) \triangle C = (A \triangle C) \triangle (A \backslash B)$
I started on the righthand side of the equation and I am having trouble with verifying this identity. I only get half the answer but I cannot get the other half. For more specificness I keep getting this:
$\lnot (((A \land B) \land C)) \land ?$
Also $\triangle$ means the symmetric difference in this scenario

Comment: What half have you managed to do? Can you clarify where you get stuck? What does "$\lnot (((A \land B) \land C)) \land ?"$ mean?

Answer (score 5):

[Indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) are a nice way to prove such results. For this case, one need only note that 
\begin{align*}
   \mathbf 1_{A\cap B}=\mathbf 1_A \cdot \mathbf 1_B, \qquad \mathbf 1_{A\mathbin\triangle B} = \mathbf 1_A+\mathbf 1_B \qquad \text{and} \qquad \mathbf 1_{A\setminus B} = \mathbf 1_A(1+\mathbf 1_B).
\end{align*}
Thus, working modulo 2, we have 
\begin{align*}
   \mathbf 1_{(A\triangle C)\mathbin\triangle (A\setminus B)} &= \mathbf 1_{A\mathbin\triangle C}+\mathbf 1_{A\setminus B}\\
   &= \mathbf 1_{A}+\mathbf 1_{C} + \mathbf 1_A(1+\mathbf 1_B)\\
   &= \underbrace{\mathbf 1_A + \mathbf 1_A}_{=0} + \mathbf 1_C + \mathbf1_A\cdot\mathbf 1_B\\
&= \mathbf1_A\cdot\mathbf 1_B + \mathbf 1_C \\
&= \mathbf 1_{A\cap B}+\mathbf 1_C \\
&= \mathbf 1_{(A\cap B)\mathbin\triangle C},
\end{align*}
so it follows that $x\in (A\triangle C)\mathbin\triangle (A\setminus B)\iff x\in (A\cap B)\mathbin\triangle C$, as required.

Comment: It is an elegant solution! I think A set-difference B should be change to A set-difference C in the first right equation.

Comment: @DoyunNam Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I proved it by using de Morgan's laws and drawing various Venn Diagrams to reason out some trivial equalities. I suggest you do the same to justify each step here (otherwise the proof will be long and illegible).
\begin{align*}
   &(A\mathbin\triangle C)\mathbin\triangle(A\setminus B)\\
   &= (A\setminus C \cup C\setminus A)\setminus (A\setminus B)\cup ((A\setminus B)\setminus(A\setminus C\cup C\setminus A)) & \text{(definition of $\triangle$)}\\
 &= ((A\setminus C)\setminus (A\setminus B) \cup (C\setminus A)\setminus(A\setminus B))\cup ((A\setminus B)\setminus(A\setminus C)\cap(A\setminus B)\setminus(C\setminus A))& \text{(de Morgan's)}\\
&= (A\cap B)\setminus C)\cup(C\setminus A) \cup ((A\cap C)\setminus B\cap A\setminus B)& \text{(Venn diagram)}\\
&= (A\cap B)\setminus C \cup C\setminus A \cup (A\cap C)\setminus B& \text{(Venn diagram)}\\
&= (A\cap B)\setminus C \cup C\setminus (A\cap B)& \text{(Venn diagram)}\\
&= A\cap B \mathbin \triangle C, & \text{(definition of $\triangle$)}\\
\end{align*}
as required.