# Some properties of symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Definition**
>
> For any $A,B$ we define
>
> $$
> A\Delta B:=\{x\in A:x\notin B\}\cup\{x\in B:x\notin A\}
> $$
>   and we call it symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$.
>
> **Obsertavion**
>
> Clearly $A\Delta B\equiv A\setminus B\cup B\setminus A$
>
> **Proposizion**
>
> The following properties hold
>
> 1. $A\Delta\varnothing=A$
> 2. $A\Delta A=A$
> 3. $A\cap(B\Delta C)=(A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)$
> 4. if $A\Delta B=A\Delta C$ then $B=C$
> 5. $A\Delta B=B\Delta A$
> 6. $(A\Delta B)\Delta C=A\Delta(B\Delta C)$
>
> *Proof*. Clearly $A\Delta A=A\setminus A\cup\varnothing\setminus A=A\cup\varnothing=A$ and moreover$A\Delta A=A\setminus A\cup A\setminus A=\varnothing\cup\varnothing=\varnothing$ thus we have proved the points $1$ and $2$.
>
> Now previously we observe that for any $X,Y,Z$ it follows that 
>   $$
> x\in(X\cap Y)\setminus(Z\cap X)\leftrightarrow x\in X\wedge x\in Y\wedge\{x\notin Z\lor x\notin X\}\leftrightarrow x\in X\wedge x\in Y\wedge x\notin Z\leftrightarrow x\in X\wedge x\notin Y\setminus Z\leftrightarrow x\in X\cap Y\setminus Z
> $$ 
>   and so we conclude that $X\cap Y\setminus Z=(X\cap Y)\setminus(Z\cap X)$. So it follows that 
>   $$
> A\cap(B\Delta C)=A\cap(B\setminus C\cup C\setminus B)=(A\cap B\setminus C)\cup(A\cap C\setminus B)=(A\cap B)\setminus (C\cap A)\cup(A\cap C)\setminus (B\cap A)=(A\cap B)\Delta(A\cap C)
> $$
>   and so we have proved the point $3$.
>
> Now if $A\Delta B=B\Delta A$, that is $A\setminus B\cup B\setminus A=A\setminus C\cup C\setminus A$; and so it follows that
>   $$
> A\setminus B=(A\setminus B\cup B\setminus A)\cap A=(A\Delta B)\cap A=(A\Delta C)\cap A=(A\setminus C\cup C\setminus A)\cap A=A\setminus C
> $$
>   and so
>   $$
> A\cap B=A\setminus(A\setminus B)=A\setminus(A\setminus C)=A\cap C
> $$
>   and then
>   $$
> C\setminus A=(A\setminus C\cup C\setminus A)\setminus A=(A\Delta C)\setminus A=(A\Delta B)\setminus A=(A\setminus B\cup B\setminus A)\setminus A=B\setminus A
> $$
>   and so we conclude that $B=C$, thus we have proved the point 4.
>   Then though the commutativity of union it easy to see that $A\Delta B=B\Delta A$ and so we have proved $5$.

So as you can see I can't prove the point 6 and so I ask to prove it. Then I ask if I have well proved the point 1 to 5. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: I find that proving set facts (_especially_ when the symmetric difference is involved) is exponentially easier when you use indicator functions. Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3281289/301095) problem for example.

Comment: Hint: prove (or let your proof be guided by the fact) that $x\in (A\mathop\Delta B)\mathop\Delta C$ if and only if $x$ is an an odd number of the sets $A,B,C$ (in other words, if and only if $x$ is in exactly one of the sets or all three of the sets). This observation makes the claim (6) easy, and it also generalizes to arbitrary parenthesizations of set differences of arbitrarily many sets.

Comment: (2) is not correct.  Should be $A\Delta A=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m inclined to agree with Luke Collins: indicator (or characteristic) functions make this easier. In $(6)$, for instance, I would let $X=A\cup B\cup C$ and define the indicator functions

$$\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{1}_A:X\to\{0,1\}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x\in A\\
0,&\text{if }x\notin A
\end{cases}\\
&\mathbf{1}_B:X\to\{0,1\}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x\in B\\
0,&\text{if }x\notin B\
\end{cases}\\
&\mathbf{1}_C:X\to\{0,1\}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x\in C\\
0,&\text{if }x\notin C\;.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Now verify that $\mathbf{1}_{A\triangle B}=\mathbf{1}_A\oplus\mathbf{1}_B$, where $\oplus$ is pointwise addition modulo $2$:

$$(\mathbf{1}_A\oplus\mathbf{1}_B)(x)=\big(\mathbf{1}_A(x)+\mathbf{1}_B(x)\big)\bmod 2$$

for each $x\in X$. Then for each $x\in X$ you can simply appeal to the associativity of $\oplus$ to argue that

$$\begin{align*}
x\in(A\triangle B)\triangle C&\text{ iff }\mathbf{1}_{(A\triangle B)\triangle C}(x)=1\\
&\text{ iff }\mathbf{1}_{A\triangle B}(x)\oplus\mathbf{1}_C(x)=1\\
&\text{ iff }\big(\mathbf{1}_A(x)\oplus\mathbf{1}_B(x)\big)\oplus\mathbf{1}_C(x)=1\\
&\text{ iff }\mathbf{1}_A(x)\oplus\big(\mathbf{1}_B(x)\oplus\mathbf{1}_C(x)\big)=1\\
&\text{ iff }\mathbf{1}_A(x)\oplus\mathbf{1}_{B\triangle C}(x)=1\\
&\text{ iff }\mathbf{1}_{A\triangle(B\triangle C)}(x)=1\\
&\text{ iff }x\in A\triangle(B\triangle C)\;.
\end{align*}$$

$(1)$, $(2)$, and $(5)$ also follow easily from properties of $\oplus$: the constant $0$ function is an identity element, each indicator function is its own inverse with respect to $\oplus$, and $\oplus$ is commutative.

Then $(4)$ is immediate from $(1)$, $(2)$, $(5)$, and $(6)$: if $A\triangle B=A\triangle C$, then

$$\begin{align*}
B&\overset{(1)}=B\triangle\varnothing\overset{(5)}=\varnothing\triangle B\overset{(2)}=(A\triangle A)\triangle B\overset{(6)}=A\triangle(A\triangle B)\\
&=A\triangle(A\triangle C)\overset{(6)}=(A\triangle A)\triangle C\overset{(2)}=\varnothing\triangle C\overset{(5)}=C\triangle\varnothing\overset{(1)}=C\;.
\end{align*}$$

That leaves only $(3)$, which succumbs quickly when you realize that $\mathbf{1}_{A\cap B}=\mathbf{1}_A\otimes\mathbf{1}_B$,where $\otimes$ is pointwise multiplication, which distributes over pointwise addition modulo $2$:

$$(\mathbf{1}_A\otimes\mathbf{1}_B)(x)=\mathbf{1}_A(x)\cdot\mathbf{1}_B(x)\;.$$

For getting a better intuitive grasp of the symmetric difference I agree with Greg Martin: it’s useful to know (and follows easily from the indicator function approach) that the members of a symmetric difference of a finite family of sets are the things that are in an odd number of those sets.

Answer (score 0):

As Luke mentioned in the comments, indicator functions are a productive approach.

If $\oplus$ denotes 'exclusive or' the we see that
$1_{A \triangle B} = 1_A \oplus 1_B$.

It is easy to verify that $x \oplus y = y \oplus x$. This gives 5.

It is not hard to verify (use an 8 place truth table at worst) that $x\oplus (y \oplus z) = (x\oplus y) \oplus z$. This gives 6.