# Prove that Laplacian of a undirected, connected graph is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

**Problem:** Prove that Laplacian matrix $L$ of an undirected, connected graph $G$ ($G$ finite with $n$ vertices) is positive definite. Using the following property to prove
$$L = D-A,$$
where $D$ is the degree matrix $(D_{ii} = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij})$ and $A$ is the adjacency matrix.

My attempt: Let $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then
$$u^TLu = u^TDu - u^TAu = \sum_{i=1}^n(D_{ii} - A_{ii})u_i^2 - \sum_{i\neq j} A_{ij}u_iu_j.$$
On the other hand, since $G$ is connected then
$$D_{ii} - A_{ii} = D_{ii} \ge 1 .$$
In addition, for all $i,j$ we have
$$A_{ij} \le 1.$$
Therefore,
$$u^T Lu \ge \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 - \sum_{i\neq j}u_iu_j.$$
Now, I am stuck here and do not know how to continue. I hope anyone can help me with some hints.

Comment: See for example the latter part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4781268/451007) that uses indicator functions and commutativity of finite sums.

Comment: $L\mathbf 1=\mathbf 0$ which means positive definiteness is not true.  You should be able to argue positive semi-definiteness with Gerschgorin Discs.

Comment: @Rócherz Thank you a lot. But, I still cannot see how to use the reference in my problem.

Comment: @user8675309 I have solved this problem in another way by using the incident matrix and it seems quite good. But, for this approach, everything seems to be more complex.